# RewriteRule first rewrite is working but not the next one

Tags: .htaccess

I need to change country.cfm?country=xxx to xxx.html
and hotel.cfm?hotel=yyy to yyy.html

I have the following in my .htacess file:

```
# change all the country pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /country.cfm?country=$1 [L]

# change all the hotel pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /hotel.cfm?hotel=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that country is working but not hotel. If I put the hotel rewriterule before the country then the hotel works but not the country.

If I go to hotel.cfm?hotel=yyy then I am redirected to country.cfm and visa versa if I swap the rewriterules around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the exact same rewrite rule. How should the engine know that XXX.html is a country and YYY.html is a hotel when the rule matches both? Since you have the `L` flag it won't process the next one.

You need to have some difference in the URLs, for example `hotel-XXX.html` and then match to that. Then your rewrite will work.

For example:

```
# change all the country pages
RewriteRule ^country-([^/]*)\.html$ /country.cfm?country=$1 [L]

# change all the hotel pages
RewriteRule ^hotel-([^/]*)\.html$ /hotel.cfm?hotel=$1 [L]
```

for URLs like `site.tld/hotel-name.html`, or maybe

```
# change all the country pages
RewriteRule ^country/([^/]*)\.html$ /country.cfm?country=$1 [L]

# change all the hotel pages
RewriteRule ^hotel/([^/]*)\.html$ /hotel.cfm?hotel=$1 [L]
```

for URLs like `site.com/hotel/name.html`

Any difference in the match parts will suffice, even if it's a single letter in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Sami. Please help me here. Can you show me how to change this? I am afraid I don't understand. What should the rewriterule look like?

Comment: @MarthinusStrydom Added some examples

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.